# What is recommended way to include android source code in addition to android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, include

I am a new developer for android programming. I understand android SDK does not contain all classes from android source code. For example, AtCommandResult.class is missing (hiding) from android.bluetooth package in the SDK.

Sometimes, however, I want to use the hidden code in my app and I wonder what would be the best way to do that. One approach I can think of would be to include its corresponding source code in my project with different package name to avoid conflict with existing core. But problem with this approach would be I have to maintain the code by myself from that point. One or two classes are OK but you know where I am going.

Is there any better way other than bothering google to include the code in the SDK? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in rooted phone its possible.

Comment: @Padma I am not sure how my question is related to rooted phone as I am asking a question regarding programming. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a .AIDL file:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

Those can already be used to access for example in Telephony functions.

Code example here:
http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.aidl?r=13

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying here. In my project, I basically want to use a class that SDK does not provide but that android phone has inside. How can aidl solve this problem?

Comment: An aidl is like an interface for an existent class. YOu don't have to have to source of the class to compile it, just the package and methods.

Comment: Oh, I get what you are saying. Since the class is already there, I can  just create interface and stub for it and do whatever I want with it. I like it! That is a lot better than what I originally thought. Thanks